# how to execute function before starting angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

how do we execute a function before loading/starting off angular in the current ng2 CLI setup?

using SystemJS before - we can just call System.import() right after our function runs.

Answer (score 0):

ended up overriding webpackJsonP on the fly - not sure if there are elegant ways of accomplishing the same, but it works.